# json_encode PHP objects with their protected properties

Tags: php, oop

Is there any way I can set up PHP objects so that when I try to convert them to JSON, all of their protected properties will be shown?

I have read other answers suggesting I add a `toJson()` function to the object, but that may not really help me a great lot. In most cases, I have an array of objects and I perform the encode on the array itself.

```
$array = [
    $object1, $object2, $object3, 5, 'string', $object4
];

return json_encode($array);
```

Yes, I can loop through this array and call `toJson()` on every element that has such method, but that just doesn't seem right.  Is there a way I can use magic methods to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could write a serialiser, which would go through all objects (recursively), use reflection to inspect them and get their properties, write those as new unprotected arrays/objects, and then JSON-encodes them. In the end you'd have something like `serialise_to_json([$obj1, ..])`, where `serialise_to_json` contains half a ton of code. I'm sure such libraries already exist.

Comment: @deceze well that's way too complex for a solution. What I think I will do if it actually turns out to be impossible to set it up automatically is I would just add a method `toJson()` to my objects which would get their properties internally without the need of reflection

Comment: Well, you'd just have to write such a serialiser once instead of writing a method for every class; it's not really that difficult. And again, there are probably libraries already out there.

Comment: @php_nub_qq It's not *too complex*. I expect it around 25 lines of code, just start! Tip: Have a look at Reflection.. Btw, adding a `toJson()` is not possible for all kinds of objects since you can't modify internal classes. An external serializer could work for all kinds of objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface in your classes so you have full control over how it is going to be serialized. You could also create a [`Trait`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to prevent copy pasting the serializing method:

```
<?php

trait JsonSerializer {
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

class Foo implements \JsonSerializable 
{
    protected $foo = 'bar';

    use JsonSerializer;
}

class Bar implements \JsonSerializable 
{
    protected $bar = 'baz';

    use JsonSerializer;   
}

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

var_dump(json_encode([$foo, $bar]));
```

Alternatively you could use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to do what you want:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    protected $foo = 'bar';
}

class Bar
{
    protected $bar = 'baz';
}

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

class Seriailzer
{
    public function serialize($toJson)
    {
        $data = [];

        foreach ($toJson as $item) {
            $data[] = $this->serializeItem($item);
        }

        return json_encode($data);
    }

    private function serializeItem($item)
    {
        if (!is_object($item)) {
            return $item;
        }

        return $this->getProperties($item);
    }

    private function getProperties($obj)
    {
        $rc = new ReflectionClass($obj);

        return $rc->getProperties();
    }
}

$serializer = new Seriailzer();

var_dump($serializer->serialize([$foo, $bar]));
```

Comment: So it turns out that there **is** some php magic that can be done. Thank you, sir!