# how to encode magento object in json format on view file

Tags: php, magento

I want to encode this:

```
$_filters = $this->getFilters();
```

it is an object in Magento `view.phtml` file. I have tried my encoding format. So, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of that object?

Normaly, you can encode any object using [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like so:

```
$json = json_encode($_filters);
```

**Update**
It seems all properties in your object are protected. This makes them inaccessable for the `json_encode` function.

The solution for this is to build the json data yourself or add a trait to your class that serializes the protected properties. An example for the latter can be found as an [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559637/743016).

Comment: Can you post a [`var_dump`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) of the object?

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category)[256]
      protected '_filter' => 
        object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category)[267]
          protected '_categoryId' => null
          protected '_appliedCategory' => null
          protected '_requestVar' => string 'cat' (length=3)
          protected '_items' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected '_data' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...

Comment: Protected properties could be the problem. I updated my answer.