# Unable to json encode the result of wc_get_products()

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code to get the best selling products and send the result in JSON. But I am unable to encode the result of wc_get_products().

```
    $best_selling_args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'total_sales', 
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num'
     );

    $products_posts = wc_get_products( $best_selling_args );

//  var_dump( $products_posts );

    echo wp_json_encode( $products_posts );
```

Comment: 4 years later I am still trying this -.- anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_encode PHP objects with their protected properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557446/json-encode-php-objects-with-their-protected-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wc_get_products() returns array of objects that has protected data in it like

```
Array
(
    [0] => WC_Product_Simple Object
        (
            [data:protected] => values
            .
            .
            .
        )
    [1] => WC_Product_Variable Object
        (
            [data: protected] => values
            .
            .
            .
        )
    [2]
    .
    .
    .
)
```

but wc_json_encode() can't encode these protected data

So, you need to do something like bellow to get all data in json

```
<?php
$best_selling_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales', 
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num'
);

$products_data = wc_get_products( $best_selling_args );

$simplified_data = array();

foreach ($products_data as $key => $single_product_data) {
    $simplified_data[$key] = $single_product_data->get_data();
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( wp_json_encode( $simplified_data ) );
echo '</pre>';
```