# php webdriver object to string

Tags: php, json

Please help me, how to convert this type of PHP (PHP Webdriver, Selenium) Object to a string like this:

name=value; name=value; name=value; etc.

So I only need the name/value pairs from the object as a string to use it in a cURL request as Cookies.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie Object
        (
            [cookie:protected] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>
                    [value] =>
                    [path] => 
                    [domain] => 
                    [expiry] =>
                    [secure] => 
                    [httpOnly] => 
                    [sameSite] =>
                )

        )

    [1] => Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie Object
        (
            [cookie:protected] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>
                    [value] => 
                    [path] => 
                    [domain] => 
                    [expiry] =>
                    [secure] => 
                    [httpOnly] => 
                    [sameSite] =>
                )

        )

    [2] => Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie Object
        (
            [cookie:protected] => Array
                (
                    [name] =>
                    [value] =>
                    [path] => 
                    [domain] => 
                    [expiry] =>
                    [secure] => 
                    [httpOnly] => 
                    [sameSite] =>
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: If you want to convert it to JSON, just use `json_encode`. If you `json_decode` what you just encoded, you end up back where you started (with a PHP variable rather than a JSON string).

Comment: If I just json_encode it results this: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: I would expect that's because the properties within it are private or protected. As per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (did you read it??), only public properties are encoded to the JSON output. See also posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557446/json-encode-php-objects-with-their-protected-properties  for some possible workarounds.

Comment: Alternatively, do you _need_ to use JSON format _specifically_? Could you use [PHP object serialisation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead?

Comment: I'd like to send this cookies in a cURL request so I need the proper conversion for this.

Comment: You can send the output of the serialize() command in a cURL request too if you want to- it's just a string. The advantage of that is that it will contain all the properties etc of the object, including the protected and private ones. Of course, it depends what the script you're sending the cURL request too will accept, which you haven't told us. We don't know if that's another script you've written, or a 3rd-party API, or what.

Comment: I need only the name/value pairs in this format: name=value; name=value; etc. So if I'm not wrong I will have a lot of work for this after the serialisation :D

Comment: OK. If that's the format the remote API needs then JSON won't give you it either, although certainly you'd be closer than with serialize(). But since json_encode() doesn't output the non-public properties, I'd guess you'd have more luck writing your own routine involving reflection (see the link I posted earlier) to get all the properties and then generate a string in the format you need for your curl request.

Comment: P.s. if you'd specified the exact required output in your question originally, it might have saved you and I a lot of time which has been spent suggesting,  and replying to, ideas that won't meet the specification!!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameters of a [cookie](https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/Cookie.html) easily with array [destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

You also could call [getName()](https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/Cookie.html#method_getName) and [getValue()](https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/Cookie.html#method_getValue), but I like the destructuring, because you can extend it much simpler.

## Note

You may need to encode the values with [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode), but I left it out for readability.

```php
// create 10 dummy cookies
$cookies = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    $cookies[] = new \Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie('name' . $i, 'value' . $i);
}

$params = [];
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    ['name' => $name,  'value' => $value] = $cookie->toArray();
    $params[] = $name . '=' . $value;
}

var_dump(implode(';', $params));
```

```
string(131) "name1=value1;name2=value2;name3=value3;name4=value4;name5=value5;name6=value6;name7=value7;name8=value8;name9=value9;name10=value10"
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I have no time to try this solution, I've solved it with serialization and string editing, but your solution looks prettier ;-)